# stop left and right links from bleeding into each other when browser is made smaller

Tags: html, css

on the left side of my page I have a logo and a list of links then on the right side I have a blog link. When I make the browser smaller the blog link bleeds into the links on the left. How can I get the blog link to stop moving at a certain point?

[link to my problem](http://ernsteverything.com/ojk)

below is the code for the problem I'm having.

html

```
<div id='logo'>
<img src="MAIN_IMAGES/logo.png" width="255" height="71"></div>

<div id='nav'>   
      <a class="ex4" href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>           
      <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
      <a href="#dialog2" name="modal">CLIENTS</a>
      <a href="#dialog5" name="modal">ABOUT</a>          
      <a href="#dialog3" name="modal">CONTACT</a>
 </div>
 <div id='blog'> 
    <a href="http://ernsteverything.com/blog">BLOG </a>
</div>
<div id='blogM'> 
     <img src="MAIN_IMAGES/date_2.png" width="60" height="19">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {top:17px;
       clear:both;
       float:left;
       position:absolute;
       left:45px;}
#nav {position:absolute;
      top:14px; 
      left: 385px;
      min-width:800px;
      white-space:nowrap;
      color:silver;}
#blog {position:absolute;
       top:14px;right:113px;
       list-style:none;
       font-family:"Gill Sans Light";
       font-style:normal;
       font-weight:400;
       text-decoration:none;
#blogM {position:absolute;
        top:13px;
        right:43px;}
```

Comment: sorry it's   ernsteverything.com/ojk20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is in the way you are positioning the elements, you're placing them like its a pixel based coordinate grid instead of an html document. And while you CAN do it this way, it will be a major pain.  You gotta remember html was made by dinosaurs without pixels and grids and has since evolved to accomodate this but not replace.

Have a look at [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) tutorial. Your div elements are all absolutely positioned from the dimensions of the body element. Theoretically the elements will always overlap this way. However if you positioned them relatively to each other they should work together regardless of how the browser is dimensioned. The concept is a bit difficult to understand, so you kind of have to think like a dinosaur. Nested elements work much like typing letters next to each other while unnested elements are like paragraphs where a return gets put between em, making them totally independent of whats around them.

My advice to you is to get rid of that whole CSS structure and start over.  Try remodeling your DOM something like

```
    <body>
        <div id='logo'>
        </div>
        <div id='nav'>
            <div id='blog'>
                <div id='bloglinks'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This should put them in a line, and then offset them using 'left' and so on to place them where you want. [Here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is also a pretty good way to see how it works.  It's all pretty out of date, you really have to think about designing in a certain way that is counter intuitive to modular thinking.

Comment: Thanks for the help but whenever I use relative text/hyperlinks change position when the browser is zoomed in or out

Comment: zoomed? I don't think I can help you with that, its something I've never tried to control on a webpage. sorry

Comment: Sorry I mean when someone hits control +

Comment: Also I can use relative the position is different on different browsers.